# Is separate httpsession listener instance is bound with each session created?

Tags: java, web-applications, servlet-listeners

I need to add a session listener to my application. I need to know whether separate session listeners are registered with each session created or all sessions are listened by a single(per application) listener.

Answer (score 1):

The session listner will be listened to single listner for the application. 
http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/listener-in-java/

As you can see here we are configuring the listner for the web-application in web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Listener</display-name>

     <listener>
          <listener-class>com.listener.MySessionListener</listener-class>
     </listener>

</web-app>
```

So there need single session listner for the web application.

Comment: Any link to a source that can backup your answer?